# Convert XML object to a string

Tags: xml, vbscript

I need convert XML to string use Vbscript. First I create `MSXML2.DomDocument` object and load XML.

```vb
Dim XmlDoc
Set XmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
XmlDoc.Load(path_to_xml_file)
```

Then I want convert this `XmlDoc` to string with all tags. But have error in this code:

```vb
Dim xmltext As String
xmltext = XmlDoc.xml
```

I know about `.text` method, but it return only value without tags.

How to fix it?

Comment: "have error" — **What** error?!

Comment: Your second code snippet isn't valid VBScript. You should be getting an "expected end of statement" error there.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure `VBScript` supports `as`, as used in `dim xmltext as String`? Isn't that `VB` or `VBA`? I don't find any notation of `As` in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

In `VBScript` simply use

```
Dim xmltext
xmltext = xmlDoc.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have no need to parse the XML, why use `MSXML2.DomDocument` at all? I would just read the file into a variable without worrying about what it contains. Here's an example:

```
Dim fs,t,x
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set t=fs.OpenTextFile("path_to_xml_file",1,false)
x=t.ReadAll
t.close
Response.Write("The text in the file is: " & x)
```

You can read more about ReadAll [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_readall.asp).